# ReactJS - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'App'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I just create a React project using `create-react-app` and after setting up, I got this error:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'App' in 'C:\Development_Projects\international-school-fe\src'
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 4:0-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'App' in 'C:\Development_Projects\international-school-fe\src'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Here is my `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

`index.tsx`:

```ts
import App from "App";
import "common/styles/spacing/margin/index.css";
import "common/styles/spacing/padding/index.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I wonder what I did wrong, I want to set path for importing at the `src` folder, that's why I'm using jsconfig.json

Comment: Don't you mean `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I think you meant `import App from "./App"`. That should have been the default from `create-react-app` so not sure why you would have changed it

Answer (score 5):

If you are using TypScript in your project, make sure the `tsconfig.json` file exists. Otherwise, create this file manually or by running this command:

```
npx tsc --init
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make the import for `App` a relative path. Changing

```
import App from "App";
```

to

```
import App from "./App";
```

should do the trick. As to why this needs to be done, you need to start out an import with a dot to ensure that Node.JS knows you're trying to import a local file. Otherwise, Node.JS will think you're trying to import a module. You can read more about import specifiers [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers).